# Blender crashes before rendering

Tags: rendering

I am following Blender Guru's tutorial as provided in the following link

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BIUDZZMfGNI&ab_channel=BlenderGuru

I completed my coffee cup with a 2K condensation texture applied and I want to render it. However, Blender crashes and closes automatically before it even starts to render without displaying any error messages. I reduced my render sampling from 256 to 128 but it made no change. My drivers and Windows are up to date. Below is my specs for my gaming PC:

- AMD Ryzen 5 3600XT 6-core
- ASUS ROG STRIX Radeon RX 5700 XT OC
- Corsair Vengeance LPX DDR4 16GB 3200 MHz
- Samsung SSD 970 EVO 500GB
- MSI B450 Tomahawk Max

As shown in the screenshot, rendering doesn't even use up half of the RAM load so I am unsure as to why Blender keeps crashing.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem and I deleted each object and try to render again just to find which one causes the problem.
In my case it was the hair and when I turned hair in mesh object, it worked fine
Hope this will work for you also